# Count number of variables in object? - PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to count the number of variables in an object?

I have a object that is created dynamically, and I want to add each of the properties to a query to update these properties into the database.
The variable $oProperties is an object:

```
public function update_model ($id, $oProperties)
{
    $SQL = "UPDATE `table` SET ";
    $count = 0;
    foreach($oProperties as $property=>$value)
    {   
        $count++;
        $SQL .= strtolower($property)." = '".$value."'";
        if($count !== $oProperties::count()) {$SQL .= ", ";}
    }
    $SQL .= " WHERE id='".$id."';";
}
```

I need to know the amount of properties in the object to know when to stop adding the comma to the query.

Comment: which type has `$oProperties` object?

Comment: Edited the question, $oProperties is an std object

Comment: To remove the last comma you can just perform: `$SQL = substr($SQL,-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
class foo {
    private $a;
    public $b = 1;
    public $c;
    private $d;
    static $e;
}

$test = new foo;
var_dump(get_object_vars($test));
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(1)
  ["c"]=>
  NULL
}
```

or if your object has type [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.count.php), you can use `count` method:

```
$arrayobj = new ArrayObject(array('first','second','third'));
var_dump($arrayobj->count());
```

But I think will be better use something like that:

```
public function update_model ($id, $oProperties)
{
    $SQL = "UPDATE `table` SET ";
    $properties = [];
    foreach($oProperties as $property=>$value)
    {
        $properties[] = strtolower($property)." = '".$value."'";
    }
    $SQL .= implode(', ', $properties);
    $SQL .= " WHERE id='{$id}';";
    return $SQL;
}
```

Comment: Thnx, I used count(object_get_vars($oProperties)) to get the amount of variables. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayObj = (array)($oProperties);    
print_r(count($arrayObj));
```